# increase Memory Translation Table (MTT) for mellanox Connect-IB card

Tags: infiniband, mellanox

I have a fat node which has 2TB memory. With the new Connect-IB card, I want to increase the MTT, so I could register a large memory region. I found this post for [HowTo Increase Memory Size used by Mellanox Adapters](https://community.mellanox.com/docs/DOC-1120) , but it didn't mention how to increase that for Connect-IB. Could anyone give me any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try allocating memory with 1 GB hugepages and then registering it? I am not sure if this will help, though.

Comment: As far as I know the Connect-IB driver doesn't have a similar feature. You should try @AnujKalia's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the `OS`, however the `Connect-X` recipe you pointed to is linux specific, so I assume we are speaking about linux openib stack.

AFAIK, `Connect-IB` driver allocates memory from the kernel for `MTT` and other cashes dynamically.

(See drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/pagealloc.c and uses of public functions defined in this module by other drivers/net/ethernet/mellanox/mlx5/core/* modules)